# Show/Hide FloatingActionButton on ViewPager swipe

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library, floating-action-button

I have an activity that has 3 tabs. Each tabs page is a fragment which displays a RecyclerView. One of the fragment has FloatingActionButton in it. I'm implementing this Button in the Fragment's layout. I'm also making it static at the bottom right of the Fragment.

Fragment layout:

```
- CoordinatorLayout
    - RecyclerView
    - FAB (without any behavior)
```

In Activity layout, I have:

```
- CoordinatorLayout
    - AppBarLayout
        - Toolbar
        - TabLayout (SmartTabLayout)
    - ViewPager
```

The problem now is the FAB is half-hidden from the view when Toolbar is expanded, but fully shown when Toolbar is collapsed. Though this does not happen if I implement the FAB button in Activity itself. But I don't want to have the button in all of the Fragments. I'm only putting it in first Fragment.

Here is a gif I made to explain this clearer.

[image: Fab hidden]

XML for Activity layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/color_primary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewpagertab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
            android:background="@color/color_primary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

XML for Fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_white_48dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/card_list"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My question is how do I make so that the button stays visible when recyclerview is scrolled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best option would be to just put the FloatingActionButton in the Activity, and call `show()` and `hide()` in a `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`.  This way you get nice [enter/exit animations](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsVlhxNGJCNTEzNFU/components-buttons-fab-behavior_04_xhdpi_009.webm) that conform to [Material Design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button).

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            fabAdd.show();
        } else {
            fabAdd.hide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I think I'm gonna use your solution as it provides more functionality. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @AimanB One more thing, be sure to use the latest version of the support design library, they fixed many issues in the latest versions, one being the default animations shown with the `show()` and `hide()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

to the RecyclerView too.

Comment: This does not have any effect at all.