# Floating action button hidden behind navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I am trying to ads a fab to my fragment but it is hidden behind the navigation bar.  The issue is that the appear layout is interested he activities and the scroll behavior is set to the frame layout to which I attach the fragment.  How do I add this behavior to the recycler view in the fragment without having to add the toolbar to the fragment.  This is because  I have lots of fragments and just one activity ﻿

Navigation_drawer_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="close">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/PrimaryPurple"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_dasboard_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/food_queue_recycle_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/title_white" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view_no_items"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="4dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/errorImageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/empty_favourite_list"
                    android:src="@drawable/food_icon_empty" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/errorTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/errorImageView"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/large_text_size"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/empty_favourite_list"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/SecondaryBlack"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/action_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_48px"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/PrimaryPurple"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/food_queue_recycle_list"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:layout_behavior="helpers.FABCoordinatorBehavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: This type of problem is common right now when putting a FloatingActionButton in a Fragment.  FABs are really meant to go in the Activity, so that they can animate in and out.  Move your CoordinatorLayout and the FAB to the Activity layout, and just have the RecyclerView in the Fragment.  In the Activity, call show() and hide() on the FAB to show it when needed.

Comment: Ok thank you for confirming.

Comment: Similar issue here, but a little different from your setup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194672/floatingactionbutton-in-fragment-hidden-on-toolbar-collapsing

Comment: @Rohit_Ramkumar - what are those `CardView`s? I mean, is it the `RecyclerView` items?

Comment: @LinX64 that threw me off as well, but it looks like it's just a default CardView that he probably sets to `View.GONE` if there are entries in the list.  The CardView shown here is actually outside of the RecyclerView.

Comment: yup. They are the RecylerView items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel Nugent's right.you can do that like this:

Just put the `FloatingActionButton` on that mainlayout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="close">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/action_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_48px"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/PrimaryPurple"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/food_queue_recycle_list"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            app:layout_behavior="helpers.FABCoordinatorBehavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/PrimaryPurple"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_dasboard_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And then use that `RecyclerView` inside that `Fragment`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/food_queue_recycle_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/title_white" />

    <!-- not sure about this, but, it shouldn't be here -->

    <!--<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_no_items"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/errorImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty_favourite_list"
                android:src="@drawable/food_icon_empty" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/errorTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/errorImageView"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/large_text_size"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/empty_favourite_list"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/SecondaryBlack"
                android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

i wasn't sure about that `CardView` because you set the `RecyclerView` to `match_parent`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/food_queue_recycle_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/title_white" />
```

So, those card's shouldn't be there.(`unless you need to show it as error cards`) by setting `setVisibility` to `GONE` and after that, handle if there was an error, show it by: `setVisibility` == `View.VISIBLE`.

Comment: those cardviews are the error cardview when there are no items. They are different from the recyler items.

Comment: Added in the answer.